# How I make AngularJS to always bind as html even when I am using ``{{..}}`` bind style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting HTML template, and HTML data from 2 external resources.
This is for example of HTML Template

```
<div>
  {{data}}
</div>
```

This is the HTML data

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

I want to compile the HTML data, into the HTML template.

I know I can using ng-bind-html, but in my case I cannot change the template I got from external resources.
I want that the default bind `{{..}}` will be as HTML instead of text Is it possible?

**In other words:** How I make AngularJS to always bind as html even when I am using `{{..}}` bind style

Comment: You don't think it's possibile? But everything is possibile...

Comment: It's possible to do what you want to do but not in expression brackets. You'l need to find a solution.

Comment: not only is this not possible, as many others have mentioned, but it is questionable that it is even necessary at all.  Generally, saving HTML in JavaScript variables is a poor practice, with the exception being user generated content.  However, even then, 99% of the time, users shouldn't know the internals of your app to be using expressions like this anyway.  And saving HTML in JavaScript variables when it isn't necessary is a pretty big red flag that you aren't using angular to it's fullest potential.

Comment: @Claies user generated content is a significant part of many sites. Delivering html in json is very common practice. Not sure why you say it is poor practice. Anything to cite regarding that? Note that sanitization is a given

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that user generated content is important to many sites.  However, more often than not, the questions I have encountered on SO do not involve user generated content, they involve using HTML in variables to enable angular to mimic other frameworks like jQuery, trying to manipulate the DOM in ways that angular tries to avoid.  In cases where users are storing HTML in data, it is rare that angular expressions would be part of that data, unless the users are able to actively affect the structure of the app (maybe possible, but certainly dangerous).

Comment: @Claies ok... I buy that ...and see it too. Just reads funny a bit sometimes since there are very valid use cases for html in json and javascript variables

Comment: @charlietfl I try to preface those statements with "generally", "most of the time", etc., especially when the question isn't clear about the intended use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use curly braces to insert HTML to render, However, you can recompile the template with `$compile` and use `ng-bind-html`.

Basic example:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <output></output>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $compile) {
  var template = '<div>{{data}}</div>';
  template = template.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/, '<span ng-bind-html="$1"></span>');

    angular.element(document.querySelector('output')).append($compile(template)($scope));
    $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>Hello world</b>');
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/250/**

Answer (score 1):

You cant use html in `{{}}`

Angular only interpolates those braces as text. Otherwise it would be massively expensive to sanitize and would cause performance issues.

There are numerous other ways to include html also including custom directives and `ng-include`